# UWP TextBox Background when Focused

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

For some reason there's no easy way to change focused background of TextBox from the default White color.

The only way it works (I need it to be dark-ish or transparent) is to create custom textbox, paste bazzillion lines of code (from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299154.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) and then edit TWO lines:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Focused">
<Storyboard>
...
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement"
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#000000" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundElement" Soryboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.1" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

**My question is:** is there a better way to do it? Is all the other code necessary (~240 lines)? 
Thank you.

Comment: You may use [behaviors](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/) I think. Never worked with them but they should make this kind of customizing really easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to create a style and then apply it. At design time you can use the Document Outline pane in Visual Studio and right-click the TextBox. Then choose the Edit Template -> Edit Copy. Then modify that style in the same way you have done in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Do this in your App.xaml file:

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="Black" Opacity="0.2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="White"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushFocused" Color="White" Opacity="0.2"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

This will overwrite the default colors with your own custom colors for every `TextBox` in your project. If you want to apply the appearance to only some of your `TextBoxes`, define it locally for each `TextBox`:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Resources>    
        Put brushes here
    </TextBox.Resources>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Full list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox#remarks