# TextBox Stylings when Focused - WinUI 3.0

Tags: xaml, winui-3

Similar to [UWP TextBox Background when Focused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46109670/uwp-textbox-background-when-focused)

I am attempting to set some application-wide style guides for Focused TextBox elements in my application. My problem is that I would like to apply different styling to any Focused PasswordBox Elements on my page, but this solution applies the same styling to PasswordBox & TextBox.

Is there a way to explicitly apply the x:Key directive for TextBox elements only?

I was thinking there might be a way to use XAML <Style TargetType="TextBox"> but can't figure it out.

```
<Application
    x:Class="Aerloc_App.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Aerloc_App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!-- Other merged dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other app resources here -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="____"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlForegroundFocused" Color="____"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextControlBorderBrushFocused" Color="____" Opacity="1"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the default style for the TextBox control and modify its **Focused** VisualState.

You can learn how to locate the **generic.xaml** file [here](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/6940).

I brought this style from my laptop **generic.xaml** but it should also work on yours.

```xml
<Application
    x:Class="App1.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
                <!--  Other merged dictionaries here  -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!--  Other app resources here  -->

            <!--  YOUR CUSTOM COLORS  -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomTextControlBackgroundFocused" Color="HotPink" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="CustomTextControlForegroundFocused" Color="YellowGreen" />
            <SolidColorBrush
                x:Key="CustomTextControlBorderBrushFocused"
                Opacity="1"
                Color="SkyBlue" />

            <!--  THIS IS FROM generic.xaml  -->
            <Style x:Key="CustomTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
                <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{ThemeResource IsApplicationFocusVisualKindReveal}" />
                <Setter Property="ContextFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarContextFlyout}" />
                <Setter Property="SelectionFlyout" Value="{StaticResource TextControlCommandBarSelectionFlyout}" />
                <!--  Please uncomment below line if you want to enable InputValidation APIs for TextBox/ PasswordBox in Pre-Release builds  -->
                <!-- <Setter Property="ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultInputValidationErrorTemplate}" /> -->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style x:Name="DeleteButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Grid
                                                        x:Name="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                        Background="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackground}"
                                                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrush}"
                                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                                        <TextBlock
                                                            x:Name="GlyphElement"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                                                            FontSize="12"
                                                            FontStyle="Normal"
                                                            Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForeground}"
                                                            Text="&#xE10A;" />

                                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>

                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="GlyphElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>

                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonLayoutGrid"
                                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                                            To="0"
                                                                            Duration="0" />
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>

                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition
                                        x:Name="ErrorPresenterRow"
                                        Height="Auto"
                                        MinHeight="0" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ErrorIconColumn" MaxWidth="0" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="RequiredHeaderPresenter"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    Content="{StaticResource RequiredHeaderContent}"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlErrorTextForegroundBrush}"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />

                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="{ThemeResource TextBoxTopHeaderMargin}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                    FontWeight="Normal"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForeground}"
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <Border
                                    x:Name="BorderElement"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    MinWidth="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}"
                                    MinHeight="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
                                    CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}" />
                                <ScrollViewer
                                    x:Name="ContentElement"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                    IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                    IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                    ZoomMode="Disabled" />
                                <TextBlock
                                    x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    Foreground="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForeground}}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                    TextAlignment="{TemplateBinding TextAlignment}"
                                    TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}" />
                                <Button
                                    x:Name="DeleteButton"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="2"
                                    MinWidth="34"
                                    Margin="{ThemeResource HelperButtonThemePadding}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Style="{StaticResource DeleteButtonStyle}"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed" />
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="ErrorPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Grid.Column="3"
                                    x:Load="False"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlErrorTextForegroundBrush}" />
                                <ContentPresenter
                                    x:Name="DescriptionPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="2"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    x:Load="False"
                                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Description}"
                                    Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlDescriptionTextForegroundBrush}" />

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlHeaderForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundDisabled}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundDisabled}}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>

                                        <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundPointerOver}}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>

                                        <!--  THIS IS WHAT YOU WANT TO CUSTOMIZE  -->
                                        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">

                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding PlaceholderForeground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, TargetNullValue={ThemeResource TextControlPlaceholderForegroundFocused}}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CustomTextControlBackgroundFocused}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CustomTextControlBorderBrushFocused}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource CustomTextControlForegroundFocused}" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light" />
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>

                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="ButtonVisible">

                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DeleteButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="ButtonCollapsed" />

                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputValidationEnabledStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="CompactValidationEnabled" />
                                        <VisualState x:Name="InlineValidationEnabled">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenterRow.MinHeight" Value="20" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="ValidationDisabled" />

                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="InputValidationErrorStates">
                                        <VisualState x:Name="CompactErrors">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorIconColumn.MaxWidth" Value="20" />
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                <Setter Target="BorderElement.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SystemControlErrorTextForegroundBrush}" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="InlineErrors">
                                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenter.(Grid.Row)" Value="2" />
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenter.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenter.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="3" />
                                                <Setter Target="DescriptionPresenter.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                                <Setter Target="ErrorPresenter.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                                <Setter Target="BorderElement.BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource SystemControlErrorTextForegroundBrush}" />
                                            </VisualState.Setters>
                                        </VisualState>
                                        <VisualState x:Name="ErrorsCleared" />

                                    </VisualStateGroup>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And you can use it like this.

```xml
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource CustomTextBox}"/>
        <PasswordBox />
```

Comment: You can find a detailed implementation on this link: https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/restyling-winui-controls/